# Chrome extension getUrl not working in injected file

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension

I'm developing a Chrome extension, is there any way to get the `chrome.extension.getURL('file path')` method from injected file? I'm unable to access above method from injected file.

manifest.json

```
{
"name": "Name",
"version": "0.1",
"description": "Name chrome extension",
"background": {
"persistent": false,
"scripts": ["js/background.js"]
},
"permissions": [
"tabs", 
"https://*/*"
],
"content_scripts": [
{
  "matches": ["https://mail.google.com/*"],
  "js": ["js/content.js"],
  "run_at": "document_end"
}
],
"web_accessible_resources": [
"js/injected.js",
"html/popup.html"
],
"manifest_version": 2
}
```

injected.js

```
console.log("Ok injected file worked");
console.log("Url: ", chrome.extension.getURL('html/popup.html'));
```

contentScript.js

```
var s = document.createElement('script');
s.src = chrome.extension.getURL('js/injected.js');
(document.head || document.documentElement).appendChild(s);
```

Comment: See also https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9515704/building-a-chrome-extension-inject-code-in-a-page-using-a-content-script/9517879#9517879

Answer (score 18, accepted):

No you cant, once you inject the script in a page, it cannot access `chrome.extension.getURl`. But you can communicate between your `injected script` and `content script`. One of the methods is using custom events.

`mainfest.json`:

```
{
"name": "Name",
"version": "0.1",
"description": "Name chrome extension",
"background": {
"persistent": false,
"scripts": ["js/background.js"]
},
"permissions": [
"tabs", 
"https://*/*"
],
"content_scripts": [
{
  "matches": ["https://mail.google.com/*"],
  "js": ["js/content.js"],
  "run_at": "document_end"
}
],
"web_accessible_resources": [
"js/injected.js",
"html/popup.html"
],
"manifest_version": 2
}
```

In your `injected script` :

```
console.log("Ok injected file worked");


document.addEventListener('yourCustomEvent', function (e)
{
    var url=e.detail;
    console.log("received "+url);
});
```

In your `content script`:

```
var s = document.createElement('script');
s.src = chrome.extension.getURL('js/injected.js');
(document.head || document.documentElement).appendChild(s);

s.onload = function(){

  var url=chrome.runtime.getURL("html/popup.html");

  var evt=document.createEvent("CustomEvent");
  evt.initCustomEvent("yourCustomEvent", true, true, url);
  document.dispatchEvent(evt);
};
```

Comment: I'm getting undefined from injected script var      this is my content script "url=chrome.runtime.getURL('html/popup.html');

var evt=document.createEvent("HTMLEvents");
console.log("evet: ",evt);
evt.initEvent("Test initEvent", true, true, url);
document.dispatchEvent(evt);"              and this is my injected script   "document.getElementById("sendButtonID").addEventListener('click', function (e)
  {
    var url=e.url;
    console.log("received "+url);
  });"

Comment: Please read answer carefully. In your injected script you are not adding any listener for your custom event.

Comment: @BharathKumar I have edited the answer. Check if it works now

Answer (score 20):

`chrome.extension.getURL` is now depcrecated. [Docs](https://developer.chrome.com/docs/extensions/reference/extension/#method-getURL)

Use `chrome.runtime.getURL` in the background script.

You need to send a message from your `contentScript` to `backgroundScript`

eg.

```
// contentScript.js

chrome.runtime.sendMessage({ message: "popup" }, function (response) {
  //
});
```

```
// backgroundScript.js

chrome.runtime.onMessage.addListener((request, sender, sendResponse) => {
  if (request.message === "popup") {
    chrome.tabs.create({ url: chrome.runtime.getURL("popup.html") });
  }
});
```

Comment: This is closest to correct in 2022. However, you can use chrome.runtime.getURL in the content scripts as well.

Answer (score 11):

You have to mention the file_path or file_names in the web_accessible_resources of extension manifest.
EG:

```
"web_accessible_resources":[
    "styles/*",
    "yourfilename.js"
  ]
```

After that you can have have the file in injected script by calling the method.
`"chrome.extension.getURL('yourfilename.js')";`

Comment: I got this error "Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'getURL' of undefined"

Comment: see i have modified the question

Comment: Nishan you're a champion!

Comment: I am getting the same error: "Cannot read property 'getURL' of undefined". Any solution to this?

Comment: This no longer works with Manifest V3, which requires each web accessible resource entry to be an object- https://developer.chrome.com/docs/extensions/mv3/manifest/web_accessible_resources/#manifest-declaration

Comment: @frontend_friend and how can be accessed with V3?

Answer (score 8):

`getURL` is [deprecated since Chrome 58](https://developer.chrome.com/docs/extensions/reference/extension/#method-getURL).

Just replace

```
s.src = chrome.extension.getURL('js/injected.js');
```

with

```
s.src = chrome.runtime.getURL('js/injected.js');
```

Comment: Deprecated (which, admittedly, it what the docs say) suggests it will still work but you are "being naughty". with 114+ there is a "no such function" error.

Answer (score 1):

Add into extension `manifest.json`

```
"web_accessible_resources": ["*.js"]
```

From ["web_accessible_resources" manual page](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/manifest/web_accessible_resources):

> These resources would then be available in a webpage via the URL chrome-extension://[PACKAGE ID]/[PATH], which can be generated with the extension.getURL method.

Answer (score 0):

**Insert images using your content script in v3**

1. Put your images inside an images directory
2. List the image you wish you insert in your manifest using

```js
...
"web_accessible_resources": [
    {
      "resources": [ "images/image-1.jpg", "images/icon-128.png" ],
      "matches": ["https://*.google.com/*"]
    }
  ],
...
```

*You can use "/images/*" to expose everything in the extension's images/ directory*

3. Run this code inside your content-script.js

...

```js
const Image = document.createElement("img");
src = chrome.runtime.getURL("images/image-1..jpg"
buttonImage.src = src;
```

...

This should work, let me know how it goes...